# Property of closure in topology

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Could someone explain why the following is true:

$x\in \bar{A} \iff \forall_{U\in \cal{T}}: x\in U \implies U\cap A\neq\emptyset$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adherent_point (3rd line)

I'm having trouble with the proof in both ways

Comment: Put the text in the question. Then tell us what you've tried, and other thoughts.

Comment: Some people use this as the definition of the closure of a set. So it is dependent on what definitions you are using how you prove this.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The definition I'm using is that the closure of A is the intersection of all closed sets containing A. I've tried "the left to right proof", but I realized I made a mistake here and I'm checking right now

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The only thing that I have is that knowing x is in closure of A, then if x is in an open B, then B is not contained in X\A. But i guess it's insuficient to draw conclusions

Comment: If $\mathcal{T}^c$ is the family of all closed sets of $X$ (the whole space), then, according to your definitions,
$$

x \in \overline A \iff \forall C \in \mathcal{T}^c \ (A \subseteq C \implies x \in C) \iff \forall U \in \mathcal{T} \ (A \subseteq X \setminus U \implies x \notin U) \iff \forall U \in \mathcal{T} \ (x \in U \implies A \nsubseteq X \setminus U).
$$

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks, I guess I misread. I will edit this later to show equivalence of definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you defined $\overline A$ as the intersection of closed sets containing $A$, for any $x\in X$ we have:

$x\notin\overline A\Longleftrightarrow$

there exists a closed set $F\supset A$ such that $x\notin F\Longleftrightarrow$

$\exists U\in\mathcal T$, $A\cap U=\varnothing$ and $x\in U$.

Hence (taking the negations)

$x\in\overline A\Longleftrightarrow$

$\forall U\in\mathcal T$, $x\notin U$ or $A\cap U\ne\varnothing\Longleftrightarrow$

$\forall U\in\mathcal T$, $x\in U\Rightarrow A\cap U\ne\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

First from left to right. You just use the fact that $\overline{A}=intA\,\bigcup\,BdA$.

So if $x\in intA$ then the result is clear because there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $V\subseteq\,A$. So every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ , intersects $V$ and hence $A$.

If $x\in\,BdA$ then the result follows by the definition of the boundary.

Now we prove from right to left. Assume that $x\notin\,\overline{A}$. Then $x\in\,X-\overline{A}$ which is open and hence there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U\subseteq\,X\,-\overline{A}\subseteq\,X\,-A$. Which implies $U\bigcap\,A=\varnothing$ , contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalence of the two following definitions:

1. $x\in\overline A\iff \forall U\in\mathcal T\left(x\in U\implies U\cap A\neq \emptyset\right)$
2. $x\in\overline A\iff x\in\bigcap_{U\in\mathcal T,\;A\subset X\setminus U}(X\setminus U)$

$2.\iff x\notin\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal T,\;A\subset X\setminus U}U$

$\iff$ there is no open set $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $A\subset X\setminus U$

$\iff$ for all open set $U$, $x\in U\Rightarrow A\not\subset X\setminus U$

$\iff$ for all open set $U\ni x$, at least one element of $A$ must be in $U\iff1.$

Credits to the user azzif00